How to hide main layout on next js 14
I am using the App router of NextJs 14 and I have a main layout which includes a navbar and a footer, I want to hide this layout on my admin page. What's the correct way or the most optimal way to do it?

Not sure you can hide it on specific route but you can remove it from the root layout and add the navbar/footer to a layout.js/ts in a group which contains non-admin.
|/app
|/app/layout.ts (or js)
|/app/(admin)
|/app/(admin)/layout.ts
|/app/(admin)/page.ts
|/app/(non-admin)/layout.ts <-- add navbar and footer here
|/app/(non-admin)/page.ts



Yes, I was looking for a more optimal way to avoid displaying the main layout on just one page. I was considering whether conditional rendering or a similar approach could achieve this, instead of creating groups.

@willmberchiche Please consider that if you make it with conditional rendering with react/next hooks the page will be rendered in client render.
